# Unable to boot  after new kernel installation

Tags: 11.10, kernel, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I boot Ubuntu 11.10 with an old kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-ubuntu-11-10-with-an-old-kernel-version)

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop. Recently I compiled and installed a 2.6.38 for LTTng kernel trace purpose. After installation when I reboot I could not boot either to the default kernel or to 2.6.38. When I boot to these kernel it shows the following messages and then hangs:

```
Stopping Save kernel messages.     [ok]
Starting Bluetooth                 [ok]

Pulsed audio configured for per-user sessons
sand disable

edit /etc/default/sand
```

I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and updated the grub2, still not working. Kindly help me

Comment: Looks as if your graphics card is not working. Can you identify your hardware ? Support for building a custom kernel is going to be limited.